# Do violet potatoes contain more or less solanine than normal potatoes?

Tags: botany, food, toxicology, vegetable, food-chemistry

What is the solanine content of the violet potatoes? Is it more or less than in the normal potatoes?

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist I have googled the Internet for violet/black potato solanine

Comment: and what did you find? What websites did you look at? Have you tried [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be about the same.

In [Effect of Genotype and Environment on the Glycoalkaloid Content of Rare, Heritage, and Commercial Potato Varieties](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1750-3841.12443), Tables 1 and 2 list 60 different potato varieties showing glycoalkaloid concentration (solanine and chaconine are shown separately); Table 1 indicates the skin color, and Table 2 indicates the flesh color.  "Violet" is not an option, but "Blue" is, and there doesn't seem to be any particular correlation between skin or flesh color and glycoalkaloid concentration. (The potato with the highest concentration of glycoalkaloid in the flesh was a blue one, but other blue varieties were fairly low; the variety with the highest in the skin was "yellow".)